# Why is Instafeed either not loading or only loading maximum 2 pictures?

Tags: javascript, html, instagram

I have honestly been afraid to ask questions for a very long time and getting bashed but I really don't know where else to go or who else to ask.

I have jQuery loaded, I have made a key on Instagram developers account, I have unchecked the oauth and authenticated the url (both: `*.mydomain.com` & `mydomain.com` (by that I do mean the actual domain name I had purchased and not the name "mydomain"...just in case you are wondering), and I upload it all to the actual web hosting server so it is going live while I am testing it.

I have the access token and client ID; I have tried the configuration script at 3 different locations: before the closing header, before closing body tag, and on a `instagram.js` file that then has been called by it's name and location at the bottom of the page before the closing body tag.

The feed is by:

```
<div id="instagram"></div>
```

right in middle of my HTML page at the correct place that I want the pictures to load but long story short, the best I have gotten is 2 images ever after I set the limit. I feel like I am forgetting some other stuff that I have done  I added every after the "`// every time we load more, run this function`" just tonight to see if I could load more picture and it didn't load or help any.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
    target: 'instagram',
    get: 'user',
    userId: '********',
    accessToken: '*******.******.****************',
    resolution: 'standard_resolution',
    // every time we load more, run this function
    after: function() {
        var el = document.getElementById('instagram');
        if (el.classList)
            el.classList.add('show');
        else
            el.className += ' ' + 'show';
    }
});

window.onload = function() {
feed.run();
```

Hopefully I didn't forget anything. I am literally in process of learning JavaScript and then jquery but this is for a project that I need to get done. So I am actually trying to learn everything instead of copying and pasting it and hoping it works.

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Comment: are you looking to fetch more images when the breakpoint is hit? the code you added only initiates the feed and fetches the image once, it does not cover subsequent fetching events. Check out the section titled 'pagination' on the plugin's documentation: http://instafeedjs.com/

Comment: No need to be afraid, as long as the question is not one of hundred dups, and has proper spelling and formatting! Asking questions is totally fine, but show some efford in general.

Comment: @dommmm the original code I used was the basic one that it's on their site but it only loaded 2 images for some reason, then I looked at the code that was used by [http://garand.me/](Anthony Garand) (website posted as an example using instafeed) and tried his javascript and it still only loaded 2 images. Then I noticed that he had simply used the pagination code so I used his code as an example to add the example of the pagination code posted on the site to my original code and now I get no images. 
I want to load 14 images and then be able to hit load more and have it load more images.

Comment: Thanks @linusg . I'm always afraid that I over looked something or misspelled. I just need to get use to the culture :)

Comment: @BruceMathers - Honestly, there's no reason to be afraid! I get what you mean by *getting bashed*, however, normally we should be quite polite to each other, since in the end we're just humans and devs making minor mistakes all day long :D (*and sorry for not being able to contribute anything to your question but commenting this much...*)

Comment: Just another comment focusing on your problem: I have not used `Instafeed` myself, but being a passionate JS dev for a while now, I can't see anything wrong in the code snippet you gave except a missing `}` after `window.onload = function() {...` (might be a typo). However, it's good practice to cache selectors that won't change (`var el = ...` should go before `var feed = ...`), since this improves speed, even just a little. Then I would simply suggest looking into...

Comment: ... the web developer console of your browser (`Ctrl+Shift+I` in FF and Chrome), if images are added or if you get any kind of warning or error.

Comment: I highly recommend doing this server-side with this Nodejs Package: https://github.com/totemstech/instagram-node

Comment: I figured it out and I will write exactly what happened tomorrow for anyone's future reference. @linusg it was giving a few errors but one of them was to start my js document with get elment by id. 
And to be truthful I had no idea about var el was....in fact it has been added to my list of things to google as soon as I finish my work on this other project. Thank you for your kindness and taking the time out to help me out.

Comment: @Mike I had no idea that even excited. I am actually going to use it on my next project. 
Seriously, thank you guys for taking the time out and helping me out.